# beamer frame with 4 tables

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer

I have a problem in arranging 4 tables in a beamer frame. Each table contains 2 graphs that I wrote with tikz that are centered both horizontally and vertically by defining a new column type.
I tried arranging the 4 tables with minipages, but I don't understand why the table doesn't keep the size.

[image]

I am leaving you a minimum code that can be compiled.

```
\documentclass[9pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs,array} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering}m{0.3\linewidth}} 
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\centering}m{0.45\linewidth}} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}   
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}
            \centering  
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \scalebox{0.5}{
                    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{D!{\hfill}D!}
                        \toprule        
                        \large  \textsc{Real line}  &   \large \textsc{Complex plane} \tabularnewline
                        \midrule 
                        \vspace*{2.15cm}
                        \vspace*{1.4cm}
                        \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.8,>=latex]
                            \begin{axis} [xmin=-2,xmax=2,
                                ymin=-0.5,ymax=2,
                                axis equal image,
                                xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
                                axis x line=middle,
                                axis y line=none,
                                enlargelimits,
                                xlabel=$Re$,ylabel=$y$,
                                xlabel style={below, font=\normalsize },
                                ylabel style={ left, font=\Large },
                                ]
                                \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}   
                        &  
                        \vspace*{1.8cm}
                        \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=.8,>=latex]
                            \begin{axis} [xmin=-2,xmax=2,
                                ymin=-0.5,ymax=2,
                                axis equal image,
                                axis lines=middle,
                                enlargelimits,
                                xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
                                ymajorticks=false,
                                xlabel=$Re$,
                                y axis line style={draw=none, insert path={ (axis cs:0,-0.5) edge[draw, dashed, -] (axis cs:0,2)}},             
                                xlabel style={below, font=\normalsize },
                                ]
                                \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
                                \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=red] (0,0) -- (0,1);
                                \node[color=red, left] at (0,1) {\Large $i$};
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}   
                        
                        \tabularnewline
                        \bottomrule
                    \end{tabular*}
                }
            \end{table} 
        \end{minipage}%%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \scalebox{0.5}{
                    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{D!{\hfill}D!}
                        \toprule        
                        \large  \textsc{Real Line}  &   \large \textsc{Complex plane} \tabularnewline
                        \midrule 
                        \vspace*{2.15cm}
                        \vspace*{1.4cm}
                        \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.8,>=latex]
                            \begin{axis} [xmin=-2,xmax=2,
                                ymin=-0.5,ymax=2,
                                axis equal image,
                                xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
                                axis x line=middle,
                                axis y line=none,
                                enlargelimits,
                                xlabel=$Re$,ylabel=$y$,
                                xlabel style={below, font=\normalsize },
                                ylabel style={ left, font=\Large },
                                ]
                                \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}   
                        &  
                        \vspace*{1.8cm}
                        \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=.8,>=latex]
                            \begin{axis} [xmin=-2,xmax=2,
                                ymin=-0.5,ymax=2,
                                axis equal image,
                                axis lines=middle,
                                enlargelimits,
                                xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
                                ymajorticks=false,
                                xlabel=$Re$,
                                y axis line style={draw=none, insert path={ (axis cs:0,-0.5) edge[draw, dashed, -] (axis cs:0,2)}},             
                                xlabel style={below, font=\normalsize },
                                ]
                                \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
                                \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=red] (0,0) -- (0,1);
                                \node[color=red, left] at (0,1) {\Large $i$};
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}   
                        
                        \tabularnewline
                        \bottomrule
                    \end{tabular*}
                }
            \end{table}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For the moment the only solution I found was to take screenshots of the various tables and arrange them with the columns environment, but the result is very bad because it is seen in low quality and reads poorly:

[image]

Would you be able to help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your tikzpictures are wider than their cells, then you try to scale down both the table and the tikzpicture, thus they are still too large as both the tikzpictures and the table shrink equally.

---

I suggest to:

- make sure that all your tikz pictures are the same size, e.g. by adding an invisible path to them (the exact numbers in `\path (0,0) rectangle (7,4);` might need a bit of fine tuning, this was just a quick judge by eye...)
- use a single table to make the code easier
- adjust the scaling of the tikzpictures so for of them fit in a line. I used a scaling factor of `0.3` below, might again need some fine tuning...

```
\documentclass[9pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \begin{tblr}{
        colspec=XXXX,
        cells={valign=m,halign=c},
        row{1}={font={\large}}
      }
      \cmidrule[r,0.8pt]{1-2}\cmidrule[l,0.8pt]{3-4}
      Real line  &   Complex plane & Real line  &   Complex plane\\
      \cmidrule[r]{1-2}\cmidrule[l]{3-4} 
      \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.3,>=latex]
          \path (0,0) rectangle (7,4);
          \begin{axis} [xmin=-2,xmax=2,
              ymin=-0.5,ymax=2,
              axis equal image,
              xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
              axis x line=middle,
              axis y line=none,
              enlargelimits,
              xlabel=$Re$,ylabel=$y$,
              xlabel style={below, font=\normalsize },
              ylabel style={ left, font=\Large },
              ]
              \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
          \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}   
      &  
      \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=.3,>=latex]
          \path (0,0) rectangle (7,4);
          \begin{axis} [xmin=-2,xmax=2,
              ymin=-0.5,ymax=2,
              axis equal image,
              axis lines=middle,
              enlargelimits,
              xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
              ymajorticks=false,
              xlabel=$Re$,
              y axis line style={draw=none, insert path={ (axis cs:0,-0.5) edge[draw, dashed, -] (axis cs:0,2)}},             
              xlabel style={below, font=\normalsize },
              ]
              \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
              \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=red] (0,0) -- (0,1);
              \node[color=red, left] at (0,1) {\Large $i$};
          \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      &
      \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.3,>=latex]
          \path (0,0) rectangle (7,4);
          \begin{axis} [xmin=-2,xmax=2,
              ymin=-0.5,ymax=2,
              axis equal image,
              xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
              axis x line=middle,
              axis y line=none,
              enlargelimits,
              xlabel=$Re$,ylabel=$y$,
              xlabel style={below, font=\normalsize },
              ylabel style={ left, font=\Large },
              ]
              \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
          \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}   
      &  
      \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=.3,>=latex]
          \path (0,0) rectangle (7,4);
          \begin{axis} [xmin=-2,xmax=2,
              ymin=-0.5,ymax=2,
              axis equal image,
              axis lines=middle,
              enlargelimits,
              xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
              ymajorticks=false,
              xlabel=$Re$,
              y axis line style={draw=none, insert path={ (axis cs:0,-0.5) edge[draw, dashed, -] (axis cs:0,2)}},             
              xlabel style={below, font=\normalsize },
              ]
              \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=blue] (0,0) -- (1,0);
              \draw [ ->, ultra thick,color=red] (0,0) -- (0,1);
              \node[color=red, left] at (0,1) {\Large $i$};
          \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}   \\
      \cmidrule[r,0.8pt]{1-2}\cmidrule[l,0.8pt]{3-4}
      \end{tblr}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]